# java reverse code to get address from lattitude and longitude

Tags: java

I got the Answer from stackoverflow for `java reverse code to get address from lattitude and longitude`. but in that answer i cant Access the packege GeoApi Context,GeocodingResult,GeocodingApi.I am writing for java web application.could anyone tell me what are the packege or jar file i download to include those packege
my answer code is

```
GeoApiContext gtx = new GeoApiContext().setApiKey("**<<<<your-key-here>>>>**");
try {
    GeocodingResult[] gResp = GeocodingApi.newRequest(gtx)
       .latlng(new LatLng(37, -121)).await();
    System.out.println(gResp[0].formattedAddress);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jars**

If you want to download the jar, you can do it on *mvnrepository.com*: [google-maps-services-0.1.15.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/maps/google-maps-services/0.1.15/google-maps-services-0.1.15.jar)

**Maven**

If you are using maven here are the coordinates:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.15</version>
</dependency>
```

More informations you will find here: [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

Comment: @vignesh you will find it in package: `com.google.maps.model`